# Noisy Gradient Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, gradient, effects

[image: Example of a Noisy Gradient]

What techniques are out there that allow you to create a gradient like the ones pictured above? Is this a product of a specific brush set? Or is there some type of Noise Manipulation / Gradient Pattern going on in this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to create a gradient that goes from black to 0% opacity white **(it won't work if you use 100% opacity white)**

[image]

Then change the layer blend mode to `Dissolve`

[image]

Et voila!

[image]

You could also convert the layer to a `Smart Object` to "save" the effect so you can then add extra blending options such as `Multiply`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like very coarse use of the Noise Filter in Photoshop.

No effort has been made to match the curvature of the cylinders, so it's probably gradients of Black to Transparent that have then had Noise applied to them.